# Removing tags in HTML using BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing, lxml

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment
import re
id = 1

def makeformat(path):
global id
html = open(path, "r", encoding="utf-8")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), "lxml", from_encoding="utf-8")
html.close()

    with open("document.txt", "a", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        path = str(path.replace("./document/", "").replace("\\", "/"))
        f.write("<DOC>\n<ID> " + str(id) + " </ID>\n")
        f.write("<URL> http://" + path + " </URL>\n")

        if not(soup.title is None):
            f.write("<TITLE>" + str(soup.title.get_text(strip=True)) + "</TITLE>\n")

        [tag.extract() for tag in soup.find_all(['script', 'style', 'noscript'])]
        [comment.extract() for comment in soup.findAll(text=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment))]

        f.write("<BODY>\n")
            for line in soup.body.strings:
            f.write(re.sub("\s\s+", "\n", repr(line).rstrip()).replace("\'", "") + "\n")

        f.write("\n</BODY>\n</DOC>\n\n")
    id += 1
```

I want to make an XML format that uses a string in a body tag that can remove style, script, and comments.

I tried to remove the tags using BeautifulSoup4, but I encountered the following error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next_element'

Why am I getting this error, and how can I solve it?

The code works if I don't run `extract()` to remove the tags.

Comment: Not clear what the question is. Anyway, in what line does it throw an error? You are having both ``tag.extract()`` and ``comment.extract()``. The way you identify comments seems prone to error to me. I am not sure that the ``soup.findAll(text=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment))`` will return something

Comment: error is ouccur for line in soup.body.strings: <-this line  if i remove tag.extract(), comment.extract() line, code can run.....

Comment: If i add ***soup = BeautifulSoup(soup.prettify(), 'lxml')***  upper ***for line in soup.body.strings:*** code it works fine.  extract() method is destroyed parsing tree ???

Comment: _"extract() method is destroyed parsing tree"_. No it shouldn't according to the docs but it would be better if you send an example html text to test

Comment: i crawling this site: http://home.kangwon.ac.kr/main/html/campuslife/academic_02.jsp  upper code doesn't work...